# Is it possible to authenticate for access to SSAS (on-premise) using Azure Active Directory credentials

Tags: azure-active-directory, ssas

I have an **on-premises** 2019 (**15**) instance of **SSAS** in **tabular** mode. I also have an **Azure Active Directory** with multiple users.

When connecting to the SSAS instance through SSMS there are 3 available authentication methods:

1. Windows.
2. Active Directory - with password
3. Active Directory - universal with MFA

I am returned the following message when trying to authenticate with 2 or 3:

> Cannot connect to xxxxx\xxxxxx. **The integrated security 'ClaimsToken'
>   is not supported for native connections**.
>   (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)

**How do I make it possible for AAD users to authenticate for access to on-prem use of SSAS?**

Comment: Azure Active Directory are not appropriate for on premises SSAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modes you are looking at are available for Azure Sql Databases that have been [protected with an Azure AD tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell).

On-prem SQL Server and its add-ons do not support authenticating with Azure AD.

Comment: "do not support authenticating with Azure AD." If one was to install SSAS on a Azure VM "Azure AD joined "to a Azure AD would it support it then? If not where does MS state that it's not supported? Is Azure MFA only supported for Azure Analysis Services then?